# WebSphere remote server debug configuration in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, websphere, websphere-7

I am trying to debug deployed application which is running in the remote WebSphere server version 7. When I try to configure server, I am getting error presented on the picture below. Please advise me how to configure the debug mode
[image]

I have referred following source https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-websphere-server.html#d1145856e682

Comment: You need to have local installation of WebSphere, and point to the `c:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer` folder instead.

Comment: its strange same thing i have done but its now wokring before i have reinstalled and try its work thank you

Comment: Please share the screen shots inteljii idea 14.1 debug configuration setup